# Select Country Dropdown in html page

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

> I need a select tag in html page.A dropdown to select a specific
>   country from all coutries.

Answer (score 22):

> Here it is

```
<select>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="Antartica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Bosnia and Herzegowina">Bosnia and Herzegowina</option>
    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
    <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="Cocos Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
    <option value="Congo">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="Cota D'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="Croatia">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="France Metropolitan">France, Metropolitan</option>
    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
    <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
    <option value="Heard and McDonald Islands">Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
    <option value="Holy See">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="Iran">Iran (Islamic Republic of)</option>
    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="Democratic People's Republic of Korea">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="Korea">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="Lao">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
    <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
    <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="Moldova">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
    <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
    <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
    <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
    <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
    <option value="Russia">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option> 
    <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint LUCIA</option>
    <option value="Saint Vincent">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
    <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
    <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option> 
    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="Sierra">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option>
    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
    <option value="South Georgia">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="Span">Spain</option>
    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="St. Helena">St. Helena</option>
    <option value="St. Pierre and Miguelon">St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
    <option value="Svalbard">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="Syria">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
    <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
    <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="Turks and Caicos">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="Vietnam">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="Virgin Islands (British)">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
    <option value="Virgin Islands (U.S)">Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
    <option value="Wallis and Futana Islands">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
    <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
    <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why is Saint LUCIA all caps and SriLanka one word?

Comment: Probably just typos. Thanks Prathamesh for doing the work so others don't have to, and Burrito for catching two errors. I used find/replace to quickly fix:
1. "LUCIA" to "Lucia"
2. "SriLanka" to "Sri Lanka"
3. removed "selected" from Lebanon.

Answer (score 20):

Mine is better : )

```
<select name="country" class="form-control" id="country">
        <option value="0" label="Select a country ... " selected="selected">Select a country ... </option>
        <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Africa" label="Africa">
            <option value="DZ" label="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AO" label="Angola">Angola</option>
            <option value="BJ" label="Benin">Benin</option>
            <option value="BW" label="Botswana">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BF" label="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="BI" label="Burundi">Burundi</option>
            <option value="CM" label="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="CV" label="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
            <option value="CF" label="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
            <option value="TD" label="Chad">Chad</option>
            <option value="KM" label="Comoros">Comoros</option>
            <option value="CG" label="Congo - Brazzaville">Congo - Brazzaville</option>
            <option value="CD" label="Congo - Kinshasa">Congo - Kinshasa</option>
            <option value="CI" label="Côte d’Ivoire">Côte d’Ivoire</option>
            <option value="DJ" label="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
            <option value="EG" label="Egypt">Egypt</option>
            <option value="GQ" label="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
            <option value="ER" label="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
            <option value="ET" label="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
            <option value="GA" label="Gabon">Gabon</option>
            <option value="GM" label="Gambia">Gambia</option>
            <option value="GH" label="Ghana">Ghana</option>
            <option value="GN" label="Guinea">Guinea</option>
            <option value="GW" label="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
            <option value="KE" label="Kenya">Kenya</option>
            <option value="LS" label="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="LR" label="Liberia">Liberia</option>
            <option value="LY" label="Libya">Libya</option>
            <option value="MG" label="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
            <option value="MW" label="Malawi">Malawi</option>
            <option value="ML" label="Mali">Mali</option>
            <option value="MR" label="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
            <option value="MU" label="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="YT" label="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
            <option value="MA" label="Morocco">Morocco</option>
            <option value="MZ" label="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="NA" label="Namibia">Namibia</option>
            <option value="NE" label="Niger">Niger</option>
            <option value="NG" label="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="RW" label="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="RE" label="Réunion">Réunion</option>
            <option value="SH" label="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
            <option value="SN" label="Senegal">Senegal</option>
            <option value="SC" label="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="SL" label="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
            <option value="SO" label="Somalia">Somalia</option>
            <option value="ZA" label="South Africa">South Africa</option>
            <option value="SD" label="Sudan">Sudan</option>
            <option value="SZ" label="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
            <option value="ST" label="São Tomé and Príncipe">São Tomé and Príncipe</option>
            <option value="TZ" label="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
            <option value="TG" label="Togo">Togo</option>
            <option value="TN" label="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="UG" label="Uganda">Uganda</option>
            <option value="EH" label="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
            <option value="ZM" label="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="ZW" label="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Americas" label="Americas">
            <option value="AI" label="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="AG" label="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="AR" label="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="AW" label="Aruba">Aruba</option>
            <option value="BS" label="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="BB" label="Barbados">Barbados</option>
            <option value="BZ" label="Belize">Belize</option>
            <option value="BM" label="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="BO" label="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="BR" label="Brazil">Brazil</option>
            <option value="VG" label="British Virgin Islands">British Virgin Islands</option>
            <option value="CA" label="Canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="KY" label="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
            <option value="CL" label="Chile">Chile</option>
            <option value="CO" label="Colombia">Colombia</option>
            <option value="CR" label="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
            <option value="CU" label="Cuba">Cuba</option>
            <option value="DM" label="Dominica">Dominica</option>
            <option value="DO" label="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
            <option value="EC" label="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
            <option value="SV" label="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="FK" label="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
            <option value="GF" label="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
            <option value="GL" label="Greenland">Greenland</option>
            <option value="GD" label="Grenada">Grenada</option>
            <option value="GP" label="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
            <option value="GT" label="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
            <option value="GY" label="Guyana">Guyana</option>
            <option value="HT" label="Haiti">Haiti</option>
            <option value="HN" label="Honduras">Honduras</option>
            <option value="JM" label="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="MQ" label="Martinique">Martinique</option>
            <option value="MX" label="Mexico">Mexico</option>
            <option value="MS" label="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="AN" label="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
            <option value="NI" label="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="PA" label="Panama">Panama</option>
            <option value="PY" label="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="PE" label="Peru">Peru</option>
            <option value="PR" label="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="BL" label="Saint Barthélemy">Saint Barthélemy</option>
            <option value="KN" label="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
            <option value="LC" label="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
            <option value="MF" label="Saint Martin">Saint Martin</option>
            <option value="PM" label="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
            <option value="VC" label="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
            <option value="SR" label="Suriname">Suriname</option>
            <option value="TT" label="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
            <option value="TC" label="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
            <option value="VI" label="U.S. Virgin Islands">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
            <option value="US" label="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="UY" label="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="VE" label="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Asia" label="Asia">
            <option value="AF" label="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AM" label="Armenia">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AZ" label="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="BH" label="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="BD" label="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="BT" label="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="BN" label="Brunei">Brunei</option>
            <option value="KH" label="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="CN" label="China">China</option>
            <option value="GE" label="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HK" label="Hong Kong SAR China">Hong Kong SAR China</option>
            <option value="IN" label="India">India</option>
            <option value="ID" label="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="IR" label="Iran">Iran</option>
            <option value="IQ" label="Iraq">Iraq</option>
            <option value="IL" label="Israel">Israel</option>
            <option value="JP" label="Japan">Japan</option>
            <option value="JO" label="Jordan">Jordan</option>
            <option value="KZ" label="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
            <option value="KW" label="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="KG" label="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
            <option value="LA" label="Laos">Laos</option>
            <option value="LB" label="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="MO" label="Macau SAR China">Macau SAR China</option>
            <option value="MY" label="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="MV" label="Maldives">Maldives</option>
            <option value="MN" label="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="MM" label="Myanmar [Burma]">Myanmar [Burma]</option>
            <option value="NP" label="Nepal">Nepal</option>
            <option value="NT" label="Neutral Zone">Neutral Zone</option>
            <option value="KP" label="North Korea">North Korea</option>
            <option value="OM" label="Oman">Oman</option>
            <option value="PK" label="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="PS" label="Palestinian Territories">Palestinian Territories</option>
            <option value="YD" label="People's Democratic Republic of Yemen">People's Democratic Republic of Yemen</option>
            <option value="PH" label="Philippines">Philippines</option>
            <option value="QA" label="Qatar">Qatar</option>
            <option value="SA" label="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="SG" label="Singapore">Singapore</option>
            <option value="KR" label="South Korea">South Korea</option>
            <option value="LK" label="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="SY" label="Syria">Syria</option>
            <option value="TW" label="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
            <option value="TJ" label="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
            <option value="TH" label="Thailand">Thailand</option>
            <option value="TL" label="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
            <option value="TR" label="Turkey">Turkey</option>
            <option value="TM" label="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="AE" label="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="UZ" label="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="VN" label="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
            <option value="YE" label="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Europe" label="Europe">
            <option value="AL" label="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="AD" label="Andorra">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AT" label="Austria">Austria</option>
            <option value="BY" label="Belarus">Belarus</option>
            <option value="BE" label="Belgium">Belgium</option>
            <option value="BA" label="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="BG" label="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="HR" label="Croatia">Croatia</option>
            <option value="CY" label="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="CZ" label="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
            <option value="DK" label="Denmark">Denmark</option>
            <option value="DD" label="East Germany">East Germany</option>
            <option value="EE" label="Estonia">Estonia</option>
            <option value="FO" label="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
            <option value="FI" label="Finland">Finland</option>
            <option value="FR" label="France">France</option>
            <option value="DE" label="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="GI" label="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
            <option value="GR" label="Greece">Greece</option>
            <option value="GG" label="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
            <option value="HU" label="Hungary">Hungary</option>
            <option value="IS" label="Iceland">Iceland</option>
            <option value="IE" label="Ireland">Ireland</option>
            <option value="IM" label="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
            <option value="IT" label="Italy">Italy</option>
            <option value="JE" label="Jersey">Jersey</option>
            <option value="LV" label="Latvia">Latvia</option>
            <option value="LI" label="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
            <option value="LT" label="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="LU" label="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="MK" label="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
            <option value="MT" label="Malta">Malta</option>
            <option value="FX" label="Metropolitan France">Metropolitan France</option>
            <option value="MD" label="Moldova">Moldova</option>
            <option value="MC" label="Monaco">Monaco</option>
            <option value="ME" label="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
            <option value="NL" label="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="NO" label="Norway">Norway</option>
            <option value="PL" label="Poland">Poland</option>
            <option value="PT" label="Portugal">Portugal</option>
            <option value="RO" label="Romania">Romania</option>
            <option value="RU" label="Russia">Russia</option>
            <option value="SM" label="San Marino">San Marino</option>
            <option value="RS" label="Serbia">Serbia</option>
            <option value="CS" label="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
            <option value="SK" label="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="SI" label="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="ES" label="Spain">Spain</option>
            <option value="SJ" label="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
            <option value="SE" label="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="CH" label="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="UA" label="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="SU" label="Union of Soviet Socialist Republics">Union of Soviet Socialist Republics</option>
            <option value="GB" label="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="VA" label="Vatican City">Vatican City</option>
            <option value="AX" label="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Oceania" label="Oceania">
            <option value="AS" label="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AQ" label="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="AU" label="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="BV" label="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
            <option value="IO" label="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
            <option value="CX" label="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
            <option value="CC" label="Cocos [Keeling] Islands">Cocos [Keeling] Islands</option>
            <option value="CK" label="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
            <option value="FJ" label="Fiji">Fiji</option>
            <option value="PF" label="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
            <option value="TF" label="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
            <option value="GU" label="Guam">Guam</option>
            <option value="HM" label="Heard Island and McDonald Islands">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
            <option value="KI" label="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
            <option value="MH" label="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
            <option value="FM" label="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
            <option value="NR" label="Nauru">Nauru</option>
            <option value="NC" label="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="NZ" label="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="NU" label="Niue">Niue</option>
            <option value="NF" label="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
            <option value="MP" label="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
            <option value="PW" label="Palau">Palau</option>
            <option value="PG" label="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
            <option value="PN" label="Pitcairn Islands">Pitcairn Islands</option>
            <option value="WS" label="Samoa">Samoa</option>
            <option value="SB" label="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
            <option value="GS" label="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
            <option value="TK" label="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
            <option value="TO" label="Tonga">Tonga</option>
            <option value="TV" label="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
            <option value="UM" label="U.S. Minor Outlying Islands">U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
            <option value="VU" label="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="WF" label="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is a list of countries,

**ISO-3166-1: Alpha-2 Codes**

```html
<select>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
    <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
    <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
    <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MO">Macao</option>
    <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
    <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
    <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
    <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
    <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
    <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

**ISO-3166-1: Alpha-3 Codes**

```html
<select>
    <option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="ALA">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
    <option value="ASM">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AND">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AGO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AIA">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="ATA">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="ATG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="ARG">Argentina</option>
    <option value="ARM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="ABW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
    <option value="AUT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZE">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BHS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BHR">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BGD">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BRB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BLR">Belarus</option>
    <option value="BEL">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BLZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BEN">Benin</option>
    <option value="BMU">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BTN">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BOL">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
    <option value="BES">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option value="BIH">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BWA">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BVT">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="BRA">Brazil</option>
    <option value="IOT">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="BRN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BGR">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BFA">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BDI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KHM">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CMR">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
    <option value="CPV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="CYM">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="CAF">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="TCD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CHL">Chile</option>
    <option value="CHN">China</option>
    <option value="CXR">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="CCK">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="COL">Colombia</option>
    <option value="COM">Comoros</option>
    <option value="COG">Congo</option>
    <option value="COD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="COK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CRI">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="CIV">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="HRV">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CUB">Cuba</option>
    <option value="CUW">Curaçao</option>
    <option value="CYP">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZE">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="DNK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJI">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DMA">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DOM">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="ECU">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EGY">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SLV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="GNQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="ERI">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EST">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ETH">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FLK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="FRO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJI">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FIN">Finland</option>
    <option value="FRA">France</option>
    <option value="GUF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PYF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="ATF">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="GAB">Gabon</option>
    <option value="GMB">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GEO">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DEU">Germany</option>
    <option value="GHA">Ghana</option>
    <option value="GIB">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GRC">Greece</option>
    <option value="GRL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GRD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GLP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GUM">Guam</option>
    <option value="GTM">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GGY">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="GIN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GNB">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="GUY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HTI">Haiti</option>
    <option value="HMD">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="VAT">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="HND">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HKG">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HUN">Hungary</option>
    <option value="ISL">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IND">India</option>
    <option value="IDN">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IRN">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="IRQ">Iraq</option>
    <option value="IRL">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IMN">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="ISR">Israel</option>
    <option value="ITA">Italy</option>
    <option value="JAM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JPN">Japan</option>
    <option value="JEY">Jersey</option>
    <option value="JOR">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KAZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KEN">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KIR">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="PRK">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="KOR">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="KWT">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KGZ">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LAO">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="LVA">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LBN">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="LSO">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LBR">Liberia</option>
    <option value="LBY">Libya</option>
    <option value="LIE">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LTU">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LUX">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MAC">Macao</option>
    <option value="MKD">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option value="MDG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MWI">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MYS">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MDV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="MLI">Mali</option>
    <option value="MLT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MHL">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MTQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MRT">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MUS">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="MYT">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="FSM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="MDA">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="MCO">Monaco</option>
    <option value="MNG">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="MNE">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="MSR">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MAR">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MOZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="MMR">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="NAM">Namibia</option>
    <option value="NRU">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NPL">Nepal</option>
    <option value="NLD">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NCL">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZL">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NIC">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NER">Niger</option>
    <option value="NGA">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="NIU">Niue</option>
    <option value="NFK">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="MNP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="NOR">Norway</option>
    <option value="OMN">Oman</option>
    <option value="PAK">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="PLW">Palau</option>
    <option value="PSE">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="PAN">Panama</option>
    <option value="PNG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PRY">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="PER">Peru</option>
    <option value="PHL">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PCN">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="POL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PRT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="PRI">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="QAT">Qatar</option>
    <option value="REU">Réunion</option>
    <option value="ROU">Romania</option>
    <option value="RUS">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="RWA">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="BLM">Saint Barthélemy</option>
    <option value="SHN">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
    <option value="KNA">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="LCA">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="MAF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    <option value="SPM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VCT">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="WSM">Samoa</option>
    <option value="SMR">San Marino</option>
    <option value="STP">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="SAU">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SEN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="SRB">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SYC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SLE">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SGP">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SXM">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
    <option value="SVK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SVN">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SLB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="SOM">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZAF">South Africa</option>
    <option value="SGS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="SSD">South Sudan</option>
    <option value="ESP">Spain</option>
    <option value="LKA">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SDN">Sudan</option>
    <option value="SUR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SJM">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="SWZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SWE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CHE">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="SYR">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="TWN">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="TJK">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZA">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="THA">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TLS">Timor-Leste</option>
    <option value="TGO">Togo</option>
    <option value="TKL">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="TON">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TTO">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="TUN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TUR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TKM">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TCA">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="TUV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UGA">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UKR">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="ARE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GBR">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="USA">United States</option>
    <option value="UMI">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="URY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="UZB">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="VUT">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VEN">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
    <option value="VNM">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="VGB">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option value="VIR">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="WLF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="ESH">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="YEM">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZMB">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZWE">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Also, for more formats please visit

https://www.freeformatter.com/iso-country-list-html-select.html

Comment: Thanks For putting these in a proper encoding unlike some on the mentioned website, like Aland Islands.

Comment: You sir are a hero, thank you. :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a select dropdown of countries with country name and ISO standard alpha-2 codes as values - in an array:

```
<select>
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="['Nigeria','NG']">Nigeria</option>
<option value="['Afghanistan','AF']">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="['Ãƒâ€¦land Islands','AX']">Ãƒâ€¦land Islands</option>
<option value="['Albania','AL']">Albania</option>
<option value="['Algeria','DZ']">Algeria</option>
<option value="['American Samoa','AS']">American Samoa</option>
<option value="['Andorra','AD']">Andorra</option>
<option value="['Angola','AO']">Angola</option>
<option value="['Anguilla','AI']">Anguilla</option>
<option value="['Antarctica','AQ']">Antarctica</option>
<option value="['Antigua and Barbuda','AG']">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="['Argentina','AR']">Argentina</option>
<option value="['Armenia','AM']">Armenia</option>
<option value="['Aruba','AW']">Aruba</option>
<option value="['Australia','AU']">Australia</option>
<option value="['Austria','AT']">Austria</option>
<option value="['Azerbaijan','AZ']">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="['Bahamas','BS']">Bahamas</option>
<option value="['Bahrain','BH']">Bahrain</option>
<option value="['Bangladesh','BD']">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="['Barbados','BB']">Barbados</option>
<option value="['Belarus','BY']">Belarus</option>
<option value="['Belgium','BE']">Belgium</option>
<option value="['Belize','BZ']">Belize</option>
<option value="['Benin','BJ']">Benin</option>
<option value="['Bermuda','BM']">Bermuda</option>
<option value="['Bhutan','BT']">Bhutan</option>
<option value="['Bolivia, Plurinational State of','BO']">"Bolivia, Plurinational State of"</option>
<option value="['Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba','BQ']">"Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba"</option>
<option value="['Bosnia and Herzegovina','BA']">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="['Botswana','BW']">Botswana</option>
<option value="['Bouvet Island','BV']">Bouvet Island</option>
<option value="['Brazil','BR']">Brazil</option>
<option value="['British Indian Ocean Territory','IO']">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option value="['Brunei Darussalam','BN']">Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option value="['Bulgaria','BG']">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="['Burkina Faso','BF']">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="['Burundi','BI']">Burundi</option>
<option value="['Cambodia','KH']">Cambodia</option>
<option value="['Cameroon','CM']">Cameroon</option>
<option value="['Canada','CA']">Canada</option>
<option value="['Cape Verde','CV']">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="['Cayman Islands','KY']">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="['Central African Republic','CF']">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="['Chad','TD']">Chad</option>
<option value="['Chile','CL']">Chile</option>
<option value="['China','CN']">China</option>
<option value="['Christmas Island','CX']">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="['Cocos (Keeling) Islands','CC']">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
<option value="['Colombia','CO']">Colombia</option>
<option value="['Comoros','KM']">Comoros</option>
<option value="['Congo','CG']">Congo</option>
<option value="['Congo, the Democratic Republic of the','CD']">"Congo, the Democratic Republic of the"</option>
<option value="['Cook Islands','CK']">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="['Costa Rica','CR']">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="['CÃƒÂ´te d'Ivoire','CI']">CÃƒÂ´te d'Ivoire</option>
<option value="['Croatia','HR']">Croatia</option>
<option value="['Cuba','CU']">Cuba</option>
<option value="['CuraÃƒÂ§ao','CW']">CuraÃƒÂ§ao</option>
<option value="['Cyprus','CY']">Cyprus</option>
<option value="['Czech Republic','CZ']">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="['Denmark','DK']">Denmark</option>
<option value="['Djibouti','DJ']">Djibouti</option>
<option value="['Dominica','DM']">Dominica</option>
<option value="['Dominican Republic','DO']">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="['Ecuador','EC']">Ecuador</option>
<option value="['Egypt','EG']">Egypt</option>
<option value="['El Salvador','SV']">El Salvador</option>
<option value="['Equatorial Guinea','GQ']">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="['Eritrea','ER']">Eritrea</option>
<option value="['Estonia','EE']">Estonia</option>
<option value="['Ethiopia','ET']">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="['Falkland Islands (Malvinas)','FK']">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
<option value="['Faroe Islands','FO']">Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="['Fiji','FJ']">Fiji</option>
<option value="['Finland','FI']">Finland</option>
<option value="['France','FR']">France</option>
<option value="['French Guiana','GF']">French Guiana</option>
<option value="['French Polynesia','PF']">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="['French Southern Territories','TF']">French Southern Territories</option>
<option value="['Gabon','GA']">Gabon</option>
<option value="['Gambia','GM']">Gambia</option>
<option value="['Georgia','GE']">Georgia</option>
<option value="['Germany','DE']">Germany</option>
<option value="['Ghana','GH']">Ghana</option>
<option value="['Gibraltar','GI']">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="['Greece','GR']">Greece</option>
<option value="['Greenland','GL']">Greenland</option>
<option value="['Grenada','GD']">Grenada</option>
<option value="['Guadeloupe','GP']">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="['Guam','GU']">Guam</option>
<option value="['Guatemala','GT']">Guatemala</option>
<option value="['Guernsey','GG']">Guernsey</option>
<option value="['Guinea','GN']">Guinea</option>
<option value="['Guinea-Bissau','GW']">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="['Guyana','GY']">Guyana</option>
<option value="['Haiti','HT']">Haiti</option>
<option value="['Heard Island and McDonald Islands','HM']">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
<option value="['Holy See (Vatican City State)','VA']">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
<option value="['Honduras','HN']">Honduras</option>
<option value="['Hong Kong','HK']">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="['Hungary','HU']">Hungary</option>
<option value="['Iceland','IS']">Iceland</option>
<option value="['India','IN']">India</option>
<option value="['Indonesia','ID']">Indonesia</option>
<option value="['Iran, Islamic Republic of','IR']">"Iran, Islamic Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Iraq','IQ']">Iraq</option>
<option value="['Ireland','IE']">Ireland</option>
<option value="['Isle of Man','IM']">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="['Israel','IL']">Israel</option>
<option value="['Italy','IT']">Italy</option>
<option value="['Jamaica','JM']">Jamaica</option>
<option value="['Japan','JP']">Japan</option>
<option value="['Jersey','JE']">Jersey</option>
<option value="['Jordan','JO']">Jordan</option>
<option value="['Kazakhstan','KZ']">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="['Kenya','KE']">Kenya</option>
<option value="['Kiribati','KI']">Kiribati</option>
<option value="['Korea, Democratic People's Republic of','KP']">"Korea, Democratic People's Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Korea, Republic of','KR']">"Korea, Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Kuwait','KW']">Kuwait</option>
<option value="[Kyrgyzstan','KG']">yrgyzstan</option>
<option value="['Lao People`s Democratic Republic','LA']">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
<option value="['Latvia','LV']">Latvia</option>
<option value="['Lebanon','LB']">Lebanon</option>
<option value="['Lesotho','LS']">Lesotho</option>
<option value="['Liberia','LR']">Liberia</option>
<option value="['Libya','LY']">Libya</option>
<option value="['Liechtenstein','LI']">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="['Lithuania','LT']">Lithuania</option>
<option value="['Luxembourg','LU']">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="['Macao','MO']">Macao</option>
<option value="['Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of','MK']">"Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Madagascar','MG']">Madagascar</option>
<option value="['Malawi','MW']">Malawi</option>
<option value="['Malaysia','MY']">Malaysia</option>
<option value="['Maldives','MV']">Maldives</option>
<option value="['Mali','ML']">Mali</option>
<option value="['Malta','MT']">Malta</option>
<option value="['Marshall Islands','MH']">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="['Martinique','MQ']">Martinique</option>
<option value="['Mauritania','MR']">Mauritania</option>
<option value="['Mauritius','MU']">Mauritius</option>
<option value="['Mayotte','YT']">Mayotte</option>
<option value="['Mexico','MX']">Mexico</option>
<option value="['Micronesia, Federated States of','FM']">"Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
<option value="['Moldova, Republic of','MD']">"Moldova, Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Monaco','MC']">Monaco</option>
<option value="['Mongolia','MN']">Mongolia</option>
<option value="['Montenegro','ME']">Montenegro</option>
<option value="['Montserrat','MS']">Montserrat</option>
<option value="['Morocco','MA']">Morocco</option>
<option value="['Mozambique','MZ']">Mozambique</option>
<option value="['Myanmar','MM']">Myanmar</option>
<option value="['Namibia','NA']">Namibia</option>
<option value="['Nauru','NR']">Nauru</option>
<option value="['Nepal','NP']">Nepal</option>
<option value="['Netherlands','NL']">Netherlands</option>
<option value="['New Caledonia','NC']">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="['New Zealand','NZ']">New Zealand</option>
<option value="['Nicaragua','NI']">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="['Niger','NE']">Niger</option>
<option value="['Niue','NU']">Niue</option>
<option value="['Norfolk Island','NF']">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="['Northern Mariana Islands','MP']">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option value="['Norway','NO']">Norway</option>
<option value="['Oman','OM']">Oman</option>
<option value="['Pakistan','PK']">Pakistan</option>
<option value="['Palau','PW']">Palau</option>
<option value="['Palestine, State of','PS']">"Palestine, State of"</option>
<option value="['Panama','PA']">Panama</option>
<option value="['Papua New Guinea','PG']">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="['Paraguay','PY']">Paraguay</option>
<option value="['Peru','PE']">Peru</option>
<option value="['Philippines','PH']">Philippines</option>
<option value="['Pitcairn','PN']">Pitcairn</option>
<option value="['Poland','PL']">Poland</option>
<option value="['Portugal','PT']">Portugal</option>
<option value="['Puerto Rico','PR']">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="['Qatar','QA']">Qatar</option>
<option value="['RÃƒÂ©union','RE']">RÃƒÂ©union</option>
<option value="['Romania','RO']">Romania</option>
<option value="['Russian Federation','RU']">Russian Federation</option>
<option value="['Rwanda','RW']">Rwanda</option>
<option value="['Saint BarthÃƒÂ©lemy','BL']">Saint BarthÃƒÂ©lemy</option>
<option value="['Saint Helena','Ascension and Tristan da Cunha','SH']">"Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha"</option>
<option value="['Saint Kitts and Nevis','KN']">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="['Saint Lucia','LC']">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="['Saint Martin (French part)','MF']">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
<option value="['Saint Pierre and Miquelon','PM']">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option value="['Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','VC']">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="['Samoa','WS']">Samoa</option>
<option value="['San Marino','SM']">San Marino</option>
<option value="['Sao Tome and Principe','ST']">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="['Saudi Arabia','SA']">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="['Senegal','SN']">Senegal</option>
<option value="['Serbia','RS']">Serbia</option>
<option value="['Seychelles','SC']">Seychelles</option>
<option value="['Sierra Leone','SL']">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="['Singapore','SG']">Singapore</option>
<option value="['Sint Maarten (Dutch part)','SX']">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
<option value="['Slovakia','SK']">Slovakia</option>
<option value="['Slovenia','SI']">Slovenia</option>
<option value="['Solomon Islands','SB']">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="['Somalia','SO']">Somalia</option>
<option value="['South Africa','ZA']">South Africa</option>
<option value="['South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands','GS']">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
<option value="['South Sudan','SS']">South Sudan</option>
<option value="['Spain','ES']">Spain</option>
<option value="['Sri Lanka','LK']">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="['Sudan','SD']">Sudan</option>
<option value="['Suriname','SR']">Suriname</option>
<option value="['Svalbard and Jan Mayen','SJ']">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
<option value="['Swaziland','SZ']">Swaziland</option>
<option value="['Sweden','SE']">Sweden</option>
<option value="['Switzerland','CH']">Switzerland</option>
<option value="['Syrian Arab Republic','SY']">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
<option value="['Taiwan, Province of China','TW']">"Taiwan, Province of China"</option>
<option value="['Tajikistan','TJ']">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="['Tanzania, United Republic of','TZ']">"Tanzania, United Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Thailand','TH']">Thailand</option>
<option value="['Timor-Leste','TL']">Timor-Leste</option>
<option value="['Togo','TG']">Togo</option>
<option value="['Tokelau','TK']">Tokelau</option>
<option value="['Tonga','TO']">Tonga</option>
<option value="['Trinidad and Tobago','TT']">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="['Tunisia','TN']">Tunisia</option>
<option value="['Turkey','TR']">Turkey</option>
<option value="['Turkmenistan','TM']">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="['Turks and Caicos Islands','TC']">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option value="['Tuvalu','TV']">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="['Uganda','UG']">Uganda</option>
<option value="['Ukraine','UA']">Ukraine</option>
<option value="['United Arab Emirates','AE']">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="['United Kingdom','GB']">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="['United States','US']">United States</option>
<option value="['United States Minor Outlying Islands','UM']">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="['Uruguay','UY']">Uruguay</option>
<option value="['Uzbekistan','UZ']">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="['Vanuatu','VU']">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="['Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of','VE']">"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of"</option>
<option value="['Viet Nam','VN']">Viet Nam</option>
<option value="['Virgin Islands, British','VG']">"Virgin Islands, British"</option>
<option value="['Virgin Islands, U.S.','VI']">"Virgin Islands, U.S."</option>
<option value="['Wallis and Futuna','WF']">Wallis and Futuna</option>
<option value="['Western Sahara','EH']">Western Sahara</option>
<option value="['Yemen','YE']">Yemen</option>
<option value="['Zambia','ZM']">Zambia</option>
<option value="['Zimbabwe','ZW']">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

https://jsfiddle.net/paulhodel/aqfbp3wd/2/

```
<html>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v3/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v3/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="dropdown"></div>

<script>
var countries = [
    { "text": "Afghanistan", "value": "AF" },
    { "text": "Åland Islands", "value": "AX" },
    { "text": "Albania", "value": "AL" },
    { "text": "Algeria", "value": "DZ" },
    { "text": "American Samoa", "value": "AS" },
    { "text": "Andorra", "value": "AD" },
    { "text": "Angola", "value": "AO" },
    { "text": "Anguilla", "value": "AI" },
    { "text": "Antarctica", "value": "AQ" },
    { "text": "Antigua and Barbuda", "value": "AG" },
    { "text": "Argentina", "value": "AR" },
    { "text": "Armenia", "value": "AM" },
    { "text": "Aruba", "value": "AW" },
    { "text": "Australia", "value": "AU" },
    { "text": "Austria", "value": "AT" },
    { "text": "Azerbaijan", "value": "AZ" },
    { "text": "Bahamas", "value": "BS" },
    { "text": "Bahrain", "value": "BH" },
    { "text": "Bangladesh", "value": "BD" },
    { "text": "Barbados", "value": "BB" },
    { "text": "Belarus", "value": "BY" },
    { "text": "Belgium", "value": "BE" },
    { "text": "Belize", "value": "BZ" },
    { "text": "Benin", "value": "BJ" },
    { "text": "Bermuda", "value": "BM" },
    { "text": "Bhutan", "value": "BT" },
    { "text": "Bolivia", "value": "BO" },
    { "text": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "value": "BA" },
    { "text": "Botswana", "value": "BW" },
    { "text": "Bouvet Island", "value": "BV" },
    { "text": "Brazil", "value": "BR" },
    { "text": "British Indian Ocean Territory", "value": "IO" },
    { "text": "Brunei Darussalam", "value": "BN" },
    { "text": "Bulgaria", "value": "BG" },
    { "text": "Burkina Faso", "value": "BF" },
    { "text": "Burundi", "value": "BI" },
    { "text": "Cambodia", "value": "KH" },
    { "text": "Cameroon", "value": "CM" },
    { "text": "Canada", "value": "CA" },
    { "text": "Cape Verde", "value": "CV" },
    { "text": "Cayman Islands", "value": "KY" },
    { "text": "Central African Republic", "value": "CF" },
    { "text": "Chad", "value": "TD" },
    { "text": "Chile", "value": "CL" },
    { "text": "China", "value": "CN" },
    { "text": "Christmas Island", "value": "CX" },
    { "text": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "value": "CC" },
    { "text": "Colombia", "value": "CO" },
    { "text": "Comoros", "value": "KM" },
    { "text": "Congo", "value": "CG" },
    { "text": "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the", "value": "CD" },
    { "text": "Cook Islands", "value": "CK" },
    { "text": "Costa Rica", "value": "CR" },
    { "text": "Cote D'Ivoire", "value": "CI" },
    { "text": "Croatia", "value": "HR" },
    { "text": "Cuba", "value": "CU" },
    { "text": "Cyprus", "value": "CY" },
    { "text": "Czech Republic", "value": "CZ" },
    { "text": "Denmark", "value": "DK" },
    { "text": "Djibouti", "value": "DJ" },
    { "text": "Dominica", "value": "DM" },
    { "text": "Dominican Republic", "value": "DO" },
    { "text": "Ecuador", "value": "EC" },
    { "text": "Egypt", "value": "EG" },
    { "text": "El Salvador", "value": "SV" },
    { "text": "Equatorial Guinea", "value": "GQ" },
    { "text": "Eritrea", "value": "ER" },
    { "text": "Estonia", "value": "EE" },
    { "text": "Ethiopia", "value": "ET" },
    { "text": "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "value": "FK" },
    { "text": "Faroe Islands", "value": "FO" },
    { "text": "Fiji", "value": "FJ" },
    { "text": "Finland", "value": "FI" },
    { "text": "France", "value": "FR" },
    { "text": "French Guiana", "value": "GF" },
    { "text": "French Polynesia", "value": "PF" },
    { "text": "French Southern Territories", "value": "TF" },
    { "text": "Gabon", "value": "GA" },
    { "text": "Gambia", "value": "GM" },
    { "text": "Georgia", "value": "GE" },
    { "text": "Germany", "value": "DE" },
    { "text": "Ghana", "value": "GH" },
    { "text": "Gibraltar", "value": "GI" },
    { "text": "Greece", "value": "GR" },
    { "text": "Greenland", "value": "GL" },
    { "text": "Grenada", "value": "GD" },
    { "text": "Guadeloupe", "value": "GP" },
    { "text": "Guam", "value": "GU" },
    { "text": "Guatemala", "value": "GT" },
    { "text": "Guernsey", "value": "GG" },
    { "text": "Guinea", "value": "GN" },
    { "text": "Guinea-Bissau", "value": "GW" },
    { "text": "Guyana", "value": "GY" },
    { "text": "Haiti", "value": "HT" },
    { "text": "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands", "value": "HM" },
    { "text": "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "value": "VA" },
    { "text": "Honduras", "value": "HN" },
    { "text": "Hong Kong", "value": "HK" },
    { "text": "Hungary", "value": "HU" },
    { "text": "Iceland", "value": "IS" },
    { "text": "India", "value": "IN" },
    { "text": "Indonesia", "value": "ID" },
    { "text": "Iran, Islamic Republic Of", "value": "IR" },
    { "text": "Iraq", "value": "IQ" },
    { "text": "Ireland", "value": "IE" },
    { "text": "Isle of Man", "value": "IM" },
    { "text": "Israel", "value": "IL" },
    { "text": "Italy", "value": "IT" },
    { "text": "Jamaica", "value": "JM" },
    { "text": "Japan", "value": "JP" },
    { "text": "Jersey", "value": "JE" },
    { "text": "Jordan", "value": "JO" },
    { "text": "Kazakhstan", "value": "KZ" },
    { "text": "Kenya", "value": "KE" },
    { "text": "Kiribati", "value": "KI" },
    { "text": "Korea, Democratic People'S Republic of", "value": "KP" },
    { "text": "Korea, Republic of", "value": "KR" },
    { "text": "Kuwait", "value": "KW" },
    { "text": "Kyrgyzstan", "value": "KG" },
    { "text": "Lao People'S Democratic Republic", "value": "LA" },
    { "text": "Latvia", "value": "LV" },
    { "text": "Lebanon", "value": "LB" },
    { "text": "Lesotho", "value": "LS" },
    { "text": "Liberia", "value": "LR" },
    { "text": "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "value": "LY" },
    { "text": "Liechtenstein", "value": "LI" },
    { "text": "Lithuania", "value": "LT" },
    { "text": "Luxembourg", "value": "LU" },
    { "text": "Macao", "value": "MO" },
    { "text": "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "value": "MK" },
    { "text": "Madagascar", "value": "MG" },
    { "text": "Malawi", "value": "MW" },
    { "text": "Malaysia", "value": "MY" },
    { "text": "Maldives", "value": "MV" },
    { "text": "Mali", "value": "ML" },
    { "text": "Malta", "value": "MT" },
    { "text": "Marshall Islands", "value": "MH" },
    { "text": "Martinique", "value": "MQ" },
    { "text": "Mauritania", "value": "MR" },
    { "text": "Mauritius", "value": "MU" },
    { "text": "Mayotte", "value": "YT" },
    { "text": "Mexico", "value": "MX" },
    { "text": "Micronesia, Federated States of", "value": "FM" },
    { "text": "Moldova, Republic of", "value": "MD" },
    { "text": "Monaco", "value": "MC" },
    { "text": "Mongolia", "value": "MN" },
    { "text": "Montserrat", "value": "MS" },
    { "text": "Morocco", "value": "MA" },
    { "text": "Mozambique", "value": "MZ" },
    { "text": "Myanmar", "value": "MM" },
    { "text": "Namibia", "value": "NA" },
    { "text": "Nauru", "value": "NR" },
    { "text": "Nepal", "value": "NP" },
    { "text": "Netherlands", "value": "NL" },
    { "text": "Netherlands Antilles", "value": "AN" },
    { "text": "New Caledonia", "value": "NC" },
    { "text": "New Zealand", "value": "NZ" },
    { "text": "Nicaragua", "value": "NI" },
    { "text": "Niger", "value": "NE" },
    { "text": "Nigeria", "value": "NG" },
    { "text": "Niue", "value": "NU" },
    { "text": "Norfolk Island", "value": "NF" },
    { "text": "Northern Mariana Islands", "value": "MP" },
    { "text": "Norway", "value": "NO" },
    { "text": "Oman", "value": "OM" },
    { "text": "Pakistan", "value": "PK" },
    { "text": "Palau", "value": "PW" },
    { "text": "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", "value": "PS" },
    { "text": "Panama", "value": "PA" },
    { "text": "Papua New Guinea", "value": "PG" },
    { "text": "Paraguay", "value": "PY" },
    { "text": "Peru", "value": "PE" },
    { "text": "Philippines", "value": "PH" },
    { "text": "Pitcairn", "value": "PN" },
    { "text": "Poland", "value": "PL" },
    { "text": "Portugal", "value": "PT" },
    { "text": "Puerto Rico", "value": "PR" },
    { "text": "Qatar", "value": "QA" },
    { "text": "Reunion", "value": "RE" },
    { "text": "Romania", "value": "RO" },
    { "text": "Russian Federation", "value": "RU" },
    { "text": "RWANDA", "value": "RW" },
    { "text": "Saint Helena", "value": "SH" },
    { "text": "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "value": "KN" },
    { "text": "Saint Lucia", "value": "LC" },
    { "text": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "value": "PM" },
    { "text": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "value": "VC" },
    { "text": "Samoa", "value": "WS" },
    { "text": "San Marino", "value": "SM" },
    { "text": "Sao Tome and Principe", "value": "ST" },
    { "text": "Saudi Arabia", "value": "SA" },
    { "text": "Senegal", "value": "SN" },
    { "text": "Serbia and Montenegro", "value": "CS" },
    { "text": "Seychelles", "value": "SC" },
    { "text": "Sierra Leone", "value": "SL" },
    { "text": "Singapore", "value": "SG" },
    { "text": "Slovakia", "value": "SK" },
    { "text": "Slovenia", "value": "SI" },
    { "text": "Solomon Islands", "value": "SB" },
    { "text": "Somalia", "value": "SO" },
    { "text": "South Africa", "value": "ZA" },
    { "text": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "value": "GS" },
    { "text": "Spain", "value": "ES" },
    { "text": "Sri Lanka", "value": "LK" },
    { "text": "Sudan", "value": "SD" },
    { "text": "Suriname", "value": "SR" },
    { "text": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "value": "SJ" },
    { "text": "Swaziland", "value": "SZ" },
    { "text": "Sweden", "value": "SE" },
    { "text": "Switzerland", "value": "CH" },
    { "text": "Syrian Arab Republic", "value": "SY" },
    { "text": "Taiwan, Province of China", "value": "TW" },
    { "text": "Tajikistan", "value": "TJ" },
    { "text": "Tanzania, United Republic of", "value": "TZ" },
    { "text": "Thailand", "value": "TH" },
    { "text": "Timor-Leste", "value": "TL" },
    { "text": "Togo", "value": "TG" },
    { "text": "Tokelau", "value": "TK" },
    { "text": "Tonga", "value": "TO" },
    { "text": "Trinidad and Tobago", "value": "TT" },
    { "text": "Tunisia", "value": "TN" },
    { "text": "Turkey", "value": "TR" },
    { "text": "Turkmenistan", "value": "TM" },
    { "text": "Turks and Caicos Islands", "value": "TC" },
    { "text": "Tuvalu", "value": "TV" },
    { "text": "Uganda", "value": "UG" },
    { "text": "Ukraine", "value": "UA" },
    { "text": "United Arab Emirates", "value": "AE" },
    { "text": "United Kingdom", "value": "GB" },
    { "text": "United States", "value": "US" },
    { "text": "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "value": "UM" },
    { "text": "Uruguay", "value": "UY" },
    { "text": "Uzbekistan", "value": "UZ" },
    { "text": "Vanuatu", "value": "VU" },
    { "text": "Venezuela", "value": "VE" },
    { "text": "Viet Nam", "value": "VN" },
    { "text": "Virgin Islands, British", "value": "VG" },
    { "text": "Virgin Islands, U.S.", "value": "VI" },
    { "text": "Wallis and Futuna", "value": "WF" },
    { "text": "Western Sahara", "value": "EH" },
    { "text": "Yemen", "value": "YE" },
    { "text": "Zambia", "value": "ZM" },
    { "text": "Zimbabwe", "value": "ZW" }
];

for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    countries[i].image = 'https://www.countryflags.io/' + countries[i].value.toLowerCase() + '/shiny/24.png';
}

jSuites.dropdown(document.getElementById('dropdown'), {
    data: countries,
    autocomplete: true,
    multiple: true,
    width: '280px',
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: OP asked specifically for an HTML select tag, nothing more.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan yet this is infinitely easier to parse out in python on the backend of a webapp rather than just being a static list of options

Comment: @roganjosh I understand but it still isn't what the question asks for.

Answer (score 3):

Select Tag :

```
<select>
<option value="countryname" selected="selected">Country Name</option>
</select>
```

you can write multiple `<option>` tag. The `<option>` tag is used to define the possible options to choose from.

Comment: perfect answer (y)

Comment: OP asked for an html select for all countries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the select list of countries with **ISO-3166-1: Alpha-2 Codes** as values and  with **Emoji flags** next to the country name

```
<select name="country">
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan </option>
  <option value="AX">Åland Islands </option>
  <option value="AL">Albania </option>
  <option value="DZ">Algeria </option>
  <option value="AS">American Samoa </option>
  <option value="AD">Andorra </option>
  <option value="AO">Angola </option>
  <option value="AI">Anguilla </option>
  <option value="AQ">Antarctica </option>
  <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda </option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina </option>
  <option value="AM">Armenia </option>
  <option value="AW">Aruba </option>
  <option value="AU">Australia </option>
  <option value="AT">Austria </option>
  <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan </option>
  <option value="BS">Bahamas </option>
  <option value="BH">Bahrain </option>
  <option value="BD">Bangladesh </option>
  <option value="BB">Barbados </option>
  <option value="BY">Belarus </option>
  <option value="BE">Belgium </option>
  <option value="BZ">Belize </option>
  <option value="BJ">Benin </option>
  <option value="BM">Bermuda </option>
  <option value="BT">Bhutan </option>
  <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of </option>
  <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina </option>
  <option value="BW">Botswana </option>
  <option value="BV">Bouvet Island </option>
  <option value="BR">Brazil </option>
  <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory </option>
  <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam </option>
  <option value="BG">Bulgaria </option>
  <option value="BF">Burkina Faso </option>
  <option value="BI">Burundi </option>
  <option value="KH">Cambodia </option>
  <option value="CM">Cameroon </option>
  <option value="CA">Canada </option>
  <option value="CV">Cabo Verde </option>
  <option value="KY">Cayman Islands </option>
  <option value="CF">Central African Republic </option>
  <option value="TD">Chad </option>
  <option value="CL">Chile </option>
  <option value="CN">China </option>
  <option value="CX">Christmas Island </option>
  <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands </option>
  <option value="CO">Colombia </option>
  <option value="KM">Comoros </option>
  <option value="CG">Congo </option>
  <option value="CD">Congo, The Democratic Republic of the </option>
  <option value="CK">Cook Islands </option>
  <option value="CR">Costa Rica </option>
  <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire </option>
  <option value="HR">Croatia </option>
  <option value="CU">Cuba </option>
  <option value="CY">Cyprus </option>
  <option value="CZ">Czechia </option>
  <option value="DK">Denmark </option>
  <option value="DJ">Djibouti </option>
  <option value="DM">Dominica </option>
  <option value="DO">Dominican Republic </option>
  <option value="EC">Ecuador </option>
  <option value="EG">Egypt </option>
  <option value="SV">El Salvador </option>
  <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea </option>
  <option value="ER">Eritrea </option>
  <option value="EE">Estonia </option>
  <option value="SZ">Eswatini </option>
  <option value="ET">Ethiopia </option>
  <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas) </option>
  <option value="FO">Faroe Islands </option>
  <option value="FJ">Fiji </option>
  <option value="FI">Finland </option>
  <option value="FR">France </option>
  <option value="GF">French Guiana </option>
  <option value="PF">French Polynesia </option>
  <option value="TF">French Southern Territories </option>
  <option value="GA">Gabon </option>
  <option value="GM">Gambia </option>
  <option value="GE">Georgia </option>
  <option value="DE">Germany </option>
  <option value="GH">Ghana </option>
  <option value="GI">Gibraltar </option>
  <option value="GR">Greece </option>
  <option value="GL">Greenland </option>
  <option value="GD">Grenada </option>
  <option value="GP">Guadeloupe </option>
  <option value="GU">Guam </option>
  <option value="GT">Guatemala </option>
  <option value="GG">Guernsey </option>
  <option value="GN">Guinea </option>
  <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau </option>
  <option value="GY">Guyana </option>
  <option value="HT">Haiti </option>
  <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands </option>
  <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State) </option>
  <option value="HN">Honduras </option>
  <option value="HK">Hong Kong </option>
  <option value="HU">Hungary </option>
  <option value="IS">Iceland </option>
  <option value="IN">India </option>
  <option value="ID">Indonesia </option>
  <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of </option>
  <option value="IQ">Iraq </option>
  <option value="IE">Ireland </option>
  <option value="IM">Isle of Man </option>
  <option value="IL">Israel </option>
  <option value="IT">Italy </option>
  <option value="JM">Jamaica </option>
  <option value="JP">Japan </option>
  <option value="JE">Jersey </option>
  <option value="JO">Jordan </option>
  <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan </option>
  <option value="KE">Kenya </option>
  <option value="KI">Kiribati </option>
  <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of </option>
  <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of </option>
  <option value="KW">Kuwait </option>
  <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan </option>
  <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic </option>
  <option value="LV">Latvia </option>
  <option value="LB">Lebanon </option>
  <option value="LS">Lesotho </option>
  <option value="LR">Liberia </option>
  <option value="LY">Libya </option>
  <option value="LI">Liechtenstein </option>
  <option value="LT">Lithuania </option>
  <option value="LU">Luxembourg </option>
  <option value="MO">Macao </option>
  <option value="MG">Madagascar </option>
  <option value="MW">Malawi </option>
  <option value="MY">Malaysia </option>
  <option value="MV">Maldives </option>
  <option value="ML">Mali </option>
  <option value="MT">Malta </option>
  <option value="MH">Marshall Islands </option>
  <option value="MQ">Martinique </option>
  <option value="MR">Mauritania </option>
  <option value="MU">Mauritius </option>
  <option value="YT">Mayotte </option>
  <option value="MX">Mexico </option>
  <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of </option>
  <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of </option>
  <option value="MC">Monaco </option>
  <option value="MN">Mongolia </option>
  <option value="ME">Montenegro </option>
  <option value="MS">Montserrat </option>
  <option value="MA">Morocco </option>
  <option value="MZ">Mozambique </option>
  <option value="MM">Myanmar </option>
  <option value="NA">Namibia </option>
  <option value="NR">Nauru </option>
  <option value="NP">Nepal </option>
  <option value="NL">Netherlands, Kingdom of the </option>
  <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles </option>
  <option value="NC">New Caledonia </option>
  <option value="NZ">New Zealand </option>
  <option value="NI">Nicaragua </option>
  <option value="NE">Niger </option>
  <option value="NG">Nigeria </option>
  <option value="NU">Niue </option>
  <option value="NF">Norfolk Island </option>
  <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands </option>
  <option value="MK">North Macedonia </option>
  <option value="NO">Norway </option>
  <option value="OM">Oman </option>
  <option value="PK">Pakistan </option>
  <option value="PW">Palau </option>
  <option value="PS">Palestine, State of </option>
  <option value="PA">Panama </option>
  <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea </option>
  <option value="PY">Paraguay </option>
  <option value="PE">Peru </option>
  <option value="PH">Philippines </option>
  <option value="PN">Pitcairn </option>
  <option value="PL">Poland </option>
  <option value="PT">Portugal </option>
  <option value="PR">Puerto Rico </option>
  <option value="QA">Qatar </option>
  <option value="RE">Réunion </option>
  <option value="RO">Romania </option>
  <option value="RU">Russian Federation </option>
  <option value="RW">Rwanda </option>
  <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy </option>
  <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha </option>
  <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis </option>
  <option value="LC">Saint Lucia </option>
  <option value="MF">Saint Martin </option>
  <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon </option>
  <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines </option>
  <option value="WS">Samoa </option>
  <option value="SM">San Marino </option>
  <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe </option>
  <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia </option>
  <option value="SN">Senegal </option>
  <option value="RS">Serbia </option>
  <option value="SC">Seychelles </option>
  <option value="SL">Sierra Leone </option>
  <option value="SG">Singapore </option>
  <option value="SK">Slovakia </option>
  <option value="SI">Slovenia </option>
  <option value="SB">Solomon Islands </option>
  <option value="SO">Somalia </option>
  <option value="ZA">South Africa </option>
  <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands </option>
  <option value="ES">Spain </option>
  <option value="LK">Sri Lanka </option>
  <option value="SD">Sudan </option>
  <option value="SR">Suriname </option>
  <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen </option>
  <option value="SE">Sweden </option>
  <option value="CH">Switzerland </option>
  <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic </option>
  <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China </option>
  <option value="TJ">Tajikistan </option>
  <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of </option>
  <option value="TH">Thailand </option>
  <option value="TL">Timor-Leste </option>
  <option value="TG">Togo </option>
  <option value="TK">Tokelau </option>
  <option value="TO">Tonga </option>
  <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago </option>
  <option value="TN">Tunisia </option>
  <option value="TM">Turkmenistan </option>
  <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands </option>
  <option value="TV">Tuvalu </option>
  <option value="TR">Türkiye </option>
  <option value="UG">Uganda </option>
  <option value="UA">Ukraine </option>
  <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates </option>
  <option value="GB">United Kingdom </option>
  <option value="US">United States of America </option>
  <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands </option>
  <option value="UY">Uruguay </option>
  <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan </option>
  <option value="VU">Vanuatu </option>
  <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of </option>
  <option value="VN">Viet Nam </option>
  <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British </option>
  <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S. </option>
  <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna </option>
  <option value="EH">Western Sahara </option>
  <option value="YE">Yemen </option>
  <option value="ZM">Zambia </option>
  <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of nationalities in ASP.NET Dropdown list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddNationality" runat="server" class="form-select">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="">-- Select --</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Afghan">Afghan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Albanian">Albanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Algerian">Algerian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="American">American</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Andorran">Andorran</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Angolan">Angolan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Anguillan">Anguillan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Argentine">Argentine</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Armenian">Armenian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Australian">Australian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Austrian">Austrian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bahamian">Bahamian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bahraini">Bahraini</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bangladeshi">Bangladeshi</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Barbadian">Barbadian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Belarusian">Belarusian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Belgian">Belgian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Belizean">Belizean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Beninese">Beninese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bermudian">Bermudian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bhutanese">Bhutanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bolivian">Bolivian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Botswanan">Botswanan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Brazilian">Brazilian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="British">British</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="British Virgin Islander">British Virgin Islander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bruneian">Bruneian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Bulgarian">Bulgarian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Burkinan">Burkinan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Burmese">Burmese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Burundian">Burundian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cambodian">Cambodian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cameroonian">Cameroonian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Canadian">Canadian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cape Verdean">Cape Verdean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cayman Islander">Cayman Islander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Central African">Central African</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Chadian">Chadian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Chilean">Chilean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Chinese">Chinese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of Antigua and Barbuda">Citizen of Antigua and Barbuda</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of Bosnia and Herzegovina">Citizen of Bosnia and Herzegovina</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of Guinea-Bissau">Citizen of Guinea-Bissau</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of Kiribati">Citizen of Kiribati</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of Seychelles">Citizen of Seychelles</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of the Dominican Republic">Citizen of the Dominican Republic</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Citizen of Vanuatu ">Citizen of Vanuatu </asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Colombian">Colombian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Comoran">Comoran</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Congolese (Congo)">Congolese (Congo)</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Congolese (DRC)">Congolese (DRC)</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cook Islander">Cook Islander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Costa Rican">Costa Rican</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Croatian">Croatian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cuban">Cuban</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cymraes">Cymraes</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cymro">Cymro</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Cypriot">Cypriot</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Czech">Czech</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Danish">Danish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Djiboutian">Djiboutian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Dominican">Dominican</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Dutch">Dutch</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="East Timorese">East Timorese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ecuadorean">Ecuadorean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Egyptian">Egyptian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Emirati">Emirati</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="English">English</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Equatorial Guinean">Equatorial Guinean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Eritrean">Eritrean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Estonian">Estonian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ethiopian">Ethiopian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Faroese">Faroese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Fijian">Fijian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Filipino">Filipino</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Finnish">Finnish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="French">French</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Gabonese">Gabonese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Gambian">Gambian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Georgian">Georgian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="German">German</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ghanaian">Ghanaian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Gibraltarian">Gibraltarian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Greek">Greek</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Greenlandic">Greenlandic</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Grenadian">Grenadian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Guamanian">Guamanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Guatemalan">Guatemalan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Guinean">Guinean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Guyanese">Guyanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Haitian">Haitian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Honduran">Honduran</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Hong Konger">Hong Konger</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Hungarian">Hungarian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Icelandic">Icelandic</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Indian">Indian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Indonesian">Indonesian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Iranian">Iranian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Iraqi">Iraqi</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Irish">Irish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Israeli">Israeli</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Italian">Italian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ivorian">Ivorian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Jamaican">Jamaican</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Japanese">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Jordanian">Jordanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Kazakh">Kazakh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Kenyan">Kenyan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Kittitian">Kittitian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Kosovan">Kosovan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Kuwaiti">Kuwaiti</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Kyrgyz">Kyrgyz</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Lao">Lao</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Latvian">Latvian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Lebanese">Lebanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Liberian">Liberian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Libyan">Libyan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Liechtenstein citizen">Liechtenstein citizen</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Lithuanian">Lithuanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Luxembourger">Luxembourger</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Macanese">Macanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Macedonian">Macedonian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Malagasy">Malagasy</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Malawian">Malawian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Malaysian">Malaysian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Maldivian">Maldivian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Malian">Malian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Maltese">Maltese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Marshallese">Marshallese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Martiniquais">Martiniquais</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mauritanian">Mauritanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mauritian">Mauritian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mexican">Mexican</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Micronesian">Micronesian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Moldovan">Moldovan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Monegasque">Monegasque</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mongolian">Mongolian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Montenegrin">Montenegrin</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Montserratian">Montserratian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Moroccan">Moroccan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mosotho">Mosotho</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Mozambican">Mozambican</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Namibian">Namibian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Nauruan">Nauruan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Nepalese">Nepalese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="New Zealander">New Zealander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Nicaraguan">Nicaraguan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Nigerian">Nigerian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Nigerien">Nigerien</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Niuean">Niuean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="North Korean">North Korean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Northern Irish">Northern Irish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Norwegian">Norwegian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Omani">Omani</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Pakistani">Pakistani</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Palauan">Palauan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Palestinian">Palestinian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Panamanian">Panamanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Papua New Guinean">Papua New Guinean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Paraguayan">Paraguayan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Peruvian">Peruvian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Pitcairn Islander">Pitcairn Islander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Polish">Polish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Portuguese">Portuguese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Prydeinig">Prydeinig</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Puerto Rican">Puerto Rican</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Qatari">Qatari</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Romanian">Romanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Russian">Russian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Rwandan">Rwandan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Salvadorean">Salvadorean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sammarinese">Sammarinese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Samoan">Samoan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sao Tomean">Sao Tomean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Saudi Arabian">Saudi Arabian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Scottish">Scottish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Senegalese">Senegalese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Serbian">Serbian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sierra Leonean">Sierra Leonean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Singaporean">Singaporean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Slovak">Slovak</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Slovenian">Slovenian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Solomon Islander">Solomon Islander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Somali">Somali</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="South African">South African</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="South Korean">South Korean</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="South Sudanese">South Sudanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Spanish">Spanish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sri Lankan">Sri Lankan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="St Helenian">St Helenian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="St Lucian">St Lucian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Stateless">Stateless</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sudanese">Sudanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Surinamese">Surinamese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Swazi">Swazi</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Swedish">Swedish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Swiss">Swiss</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Syrian">Syrian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Taiwanese">Taiwanese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tajik">Tajik</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tanzanian">Tanzanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Thai">Thai</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Togolese">Togolese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tongan">Tongan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Trinidadian">Trinidadian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tristanian">Tristanian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tunisian">Tunisian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Turkish">Turkish</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Turkmen">Turkmen</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Turks and Caicos Islander">Turks and Caicos Islander</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Tuvaluan">Tuvaluan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ugandan">Ugandan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Ukrainian">Ukrainian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Uruguayan">Uruguayan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Uzbek">Uzbek</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Vatican citizen">Vatican citizen</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Venezuelan">Venezuelan</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Vietnamese">Vietnamese</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Vincentian">Vincentian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Wallisian">Wallisian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Welsh">Welsh</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Yemeni">Yemeni</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Zambian">Zambian</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</asp:ListItem>
    
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Dropdown list for Countries are below

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCountry" runat="server" class="form-select">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="">-- Select --</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Albania">Albania</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Algeria">Algeria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="American Samoa">American Samoa</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Andorra">Andorra</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Angola">Angola</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Anguilla">Anguilla</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Antarctica">Antarctica</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Argentina">Argentina</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Armenia">Armenia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Aruba">Aruba</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Australia">Australia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Austria">Austria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bahamas">Bahamas</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bahrain">Bahrain</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Barbados">Barbados</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Belarus">Belarus</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Belgium">Belgium</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Belize">Belize</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Benin">Benin</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bermuda">Bermuda</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bhutan">Bhutan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bolivia">Bolivia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Botswana">Botswana</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Brazil">Brazil</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Burundi">Burundi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cambodia">Cambodia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cameroon">Cameroon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Canada">Canada</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Chad">Chad</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Chile">Chile</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="China">China</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Colombia">Colombia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Comoros">Comoros</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Congo">Congo</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Croatia">Croatia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cuba">Cuba</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Cyprus">Cyprus</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Denmark">Denmark</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Djibouti">Djibouti</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Dominica">Dominica</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ecuador">Ecuador</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Egypt">Egypt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="El Salvador">El Salvador</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Eritrea">Eritrea</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Estonia">Estonia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Fiji">Fiji</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Finland">Finland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="France">France</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="French Guiana">French Guiana</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Gabon">Gabon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Gambia">Gambia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Georgia">Georgia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Germany">Germany</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ghana">Ghana</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Greece">Greece</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Greenland">Greenland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Grenada">Grenada</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guam">Guam</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guatemala">Guatemala</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guernsey">Guernsey</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guinea">Guinea</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Guyana">Guyana</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Haiti">Haiti</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Honduras">Honduras</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Hungary">Hungary</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Iceland">Iceland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="India">India</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Indonesia">Indonesia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Iraq">Iraq</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ireland">Ireland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Israel">Israel</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Italy">Italy</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Jamaica">Jamaica</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Japan">Japan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Jersey">Jersey</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Jordan">Jordan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Kenya">Kenya</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Kiribati">Kiribati</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Kuwait">Kuwait</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Latvia">Latvia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lebanon">Lebanon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lesotho">Lesotho</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Liberia">Liberia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Lithuania">Lithuania</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Macao">Macao</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Madagascar">Madagascar</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Malawi">Malawi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Malaysia">Malaysia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Maldives">Maldives</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mali">Mali</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Malta">Malta</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Martinique">Martinique</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mauritania">Mauritania</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mauritius">Mauritius</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mayotte">Mayotte</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mexico">Mexico</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Monaco">Monaco</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mongolia">Mongolia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Montenegro">Montenegro</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Montserrat">Montserrat</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Morocco">Morocco</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Mozambique">Mozambique</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Myanmar">Myanmar</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Namibia">Namibia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Nauru">Nauru</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Nepal">Nepal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Netherlands">Netherlands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="New Zealand">New Zealand</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Niger">Niger</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Nigeria">Nigeria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Niue">Niue</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Norway">Norway</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Oman">Oman</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Pakistan">Pakistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Palau">Palau</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Panama">Panama</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Paraguay">Paraguay</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Peru">Peru</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Philippines">Philippines</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Poland">Poland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Portugal">Portugal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Qatar">Qatar</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Reunion">Reunion</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Romania">Romania</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Rwanda">Rwanda</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Samoa">Samoa</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="San Marino">San Marino</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Senegal">Senegal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Serbia">Serbia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Seychelles">Seychelles</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Singapore">Singapore</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Slovakia">Slovakia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Slovenia">Slovenia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Somalia">Somalia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="South Africa">South Africa</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Spain">Spain</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sudan">Sudan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Suriname">Suriname</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Swaziland">Swaziland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sweden">Sweden</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Switzerland">Switzerland</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Taiwan">Taiwan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Thailand">Thailand</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Togo">Togo</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Tokelau">Tokelau</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Tonga">Tonga</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Tunisia">Tunisia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Turkey">Turkey</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Uganda">Uganda</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Ukraine">Ukraine</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="United States">United States</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Uruguay">Uruguay</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Venezuela">Venezuela</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Yemen">Yemen</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Zambia">Zambia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```