# How to add country to a validation form

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add country to a validation form, creating a validation form with JavaScript, html and CSS but don't know how to add countries to my form, please help. also i need help on CSS, want when mouse is hovered over the submit button and the form box, it will change color

Comment: Show me your current code please

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is built-in dropdown for countries in html but [this link](https://www.html-code-generator.com/html/drop-down/country-names) might be helpful. OR [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388003/select-country-dropdown-in-html-page)

for button

```
button:hover{
   background-color: some custom color
}
```

Is this what you wanted?